# How to use variables in a PL/pgSQL function with dynamic queries?

Tags: postgresql, functions, tempdb

...and when must I use `EXECUTE` ... `quote_ident(variable)`?

Taking an input to the function as text and storing part as a variable:

```
wtype := split_part(message, ' ', 4); 
realval := split_part(message, ' ', 6)::float8;
```

I then wish to use the text the variables hold in a statement,
I think this is the only way:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..temp_weather') IS NOT NULL) THEN
    -- exists: insert value into proper column
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE temp_weather 
        SET ' || quote_ident(wtype) || ' = ' || quote_ident(realval) || '
        WHERE tID NOT NULL';
```

Is this effective/is this efficiently written or am I making this way overcomplicated?

Comment: What is `object_id()`?  And `tempdb`?  Also, `quote_ident()` is necessary only for database object names, it would throw an error if applied to column values. The second example with the `INSERT` does not need a dynamic query at all.  BTW, which PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: This is wrong in multiple ways and can be improved in more ways. Please provide a complete example function including function header and how you intend to call it. Obviously your version of Postgres, too.

Comment: I'm using 9.4, I realize most of the `quote_ident()` calls are unnecessary, the only one I'm not sure of is the call for `wtype` as the variable is a text field and i needed to use the text as the name of a column during an insert query. `tempdb` and `object_id()` are part of postgresql, `tempdb` is part of the implementation of temporary tables and `object_id()` is a built-in function for checking existence (i think, i really have no idea I started using SQL a week ago.) Also, why did my "thanks for..." get removed? Just trying to be courteous.